# SQL query for knowing the popular hashtag from a column, that has a list of hashtags stored as an array

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to find a popular hashtag from a table that looks something like this.

```
| Tweet_id |                 Hashtags                |
-----------------------------------------------------
|    id1   | [hashtag1,hashtag2,hashtag3]            |
|    id2   | [hashtag2,hashtag4]                     |
|    id3   | []                                      |
|    id4   | [hashtag1]                              |
```

So i am trying to print the top most occurred hashtag from the table using a `MySQL` Query. From the research i have done on this, i was able to retrieve only a single hashtag using `FIND_IN_SET`. But as it can be seen the number of hashtags in the columns are different for rows. And my query has to search all the hashtags in the array and produce the result.

Note:
What i really am doing is that i have a json file and i am using sparks sqlContext to convert the json and register it as a table. The table looks like the above. I am using `sqlContext.sql("//sqlquery//")` to retrieve data from these tables.

Update:-
This is the Schema

```
root
 |-- hashtag: array (nullable = true)
 |     |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: change table structure if possible, never store data in in comma separated form

Comment: Hey,thanks for the quick reply.. I am not supposed to change the table structure. This is one of the conditions that my professor has put in my project.

Comment: Can you show an output from `printSchema`?

Comment: Presumably your professor is a psychopath?

Comment: lol...he really is one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split and count:

```
SELECT sub.val AS `HashTag`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.HashTag, ',', n.n), ',', -1) AS val
  FROM (SELECT Substring(HashTag, 2, LENGTH(HashTag) - 2) AS HashTag FROM tab) AS t 
  CROSS JOIN 
  (
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
  ) n
   WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.HashTag) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.HashTag, ',', '')))
) sub
WHERE val <> ''
GROUP BY sub.val
ORDER BY `count` DESC
-- LIMIT 1;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5c64/7/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════╗
║   val     ║ count ║
╠═══════════╬═══════╣
║ hashtag1  ║     2 ║
║ hashtag2  ║     2 ║
║ hashtag4  ║     1 ║
║ hashtag3  ║     1 ║
╚═══════════╩═══════╝
```

Anyway you should normalize your table.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer, This is what i needed.I didn't check it in my spark shell. But it does look like its gonna work.

Comment: I really doubt the OP's professor intended students to come up with something like that! Agreed, normalizing the table is the way to fo. @ArCh3r, please review the progfessor's constraints on your answer carefully, I suspect you've misinterpreted them.